# TradingView WebChart in UWP

Tags: html, xaml, uwp

I'm pretty new to coding, but I would like to create a simple UWP app for my phone just to see FX charts on-the-go - sadly, there are not too much related apps for this -.

I really like TradingView's WebCharts, and they provide real-time web widgets, what would fit for the task :)

Is it possible to show these in a UWP App?

Example:

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d33t3vvu2t2yu5.cloudfront.net/tv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
new TradingView.widget({
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "White",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "en",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "hideideas": true,
  "show_popup_button": true,
  "popup_width": "1000",
  "popup_height": "650"
});
</script>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Thank you for the answers :)

Matt

Answer (score 0):

TradingView's WebCharts js lib targets Web Application. It's not 100% fit for UWP(JS) Application.

I made a demo and found that the `document.write` inside TradingView's JS library will crash the UWP(JS) Application.

So as a personal workaround for using TradingView in UWP. You can do the following steps:

1. Download the WebCharts js lib from `https://d33t3vvu2t2yu5.cloudfront.net/tv.js` and add the js lib to your project.(UWP doesn't support remote js reference).
2. Open `package.appxmanifest` file->`Content URIs` tag->add `https://dwq4do82y8xi7.cloudfront.net` like below:
   [image]
3. Open the downloaded js lib and search for `document.write(widgetHtml)`. Modify the result line like below:

   ```
   /*document.write(widgetHtml)*/document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=widgetHtml
   ```
4. Add a `Div` with `id="container"` to html:

   ```
   <body>
      <div id="container"></div>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
   </body>
   ```

Now you can get the WebCharts run in UWP App.

Here is the complete Demo: [TradingViewSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/TradingViewSample).